# Unable to synchronize blocking read and write on FIFO

Tags: c, linux

I'm making a very simple program which is composed of a small API used by clients and a server process. Client processes and server process communicate by a couple of FIFO (one with the requests to the server and one with the responses from the server).

- the server keeps on reading the requests FIFO with a blocking read (O_RDWR flag)
- the clients write a request on the requests FIFO (O_WRONLY flag)
- the server read the request, it works on it and write the response on the responses FIFO (O_WRONLY flag)
- the clients read the response (O_RDONLY flag): if the server hasn't to communicate any data (I mean an undefined long buffer), then the response written on the FIFO is enough and the job is done
- else...
- the client reads in the response that the server is going to send data, so it opens the responses FIFO again (O_RDONLY flag)
- server writes data with (O_WRONLY flag)

The last write doesn't seem to block the server process until a client is reading on the other side: why? what am I missing?
In order to achieve my goal I had to put a sleep(1) before the write call but this works only with some kind of requests to the server: how can I help you to help me?

SERVER CODE

```
                /* until here everything is ok: client read the response and waits for the buffer */
                sleep(1);
                /* open the FIFO and send the buffer */
                if((fifofrom = open(FIFOFROMMMBOXD, O_WRONLY)) == -1)   logMmboxd("error in opening FIFOFROM again for the buffer\n", 1);
                else                                                    logMmboxd("opened FIFOFROM again for the buffer\n", 0);

                if((write(fifofrom, mails, sizeof(mmbox_mail_complete)*m)) != sizeof(mmbox_mail_complete)*m)   logMmboxd("error in writing FIFOFROM again for the buffer\n", 1);
                else                                                                                           logMmboxd("written on FIFOFROM again for the buffer\n", 0);      
                close(fifofrom); 

                logMmboxd("messages list definitely sent\n", 0);
```

CLIENT CODE

```
void lockUp(Request *request, Response *response, void **buffer)
{
int fifofrom, fifoto, lock;     

/* lockto access the FIFOs */
if((lock = open(LOCK, O_RDONLY)) == -1)   logMmboxman("error in opening LOCK\n", 1);
else                                      logMmboxman("opened LOCK\n", 0);

if(flock(lock, LOCK_EX) == -1)            logMmboxman("error in acquiring LOCK\n", 1);              
else                                      logMmboxman("acquired LOCK\n", 0);  

/* open the FIFO and write the request */
if((fifoto = open(FIFOTOMMBOXD, O_WRONLY)) == -1)   logMmboxman("error in opening FIFOTO\n", 1); 
else                                                logMmboxman("opened FIFOTO\n", 0);  

if((write(fifoto, request, sizeof(Request))) != sizeof(Request))   logMmboxman("error in writing FIFOTO\n", 1);
else                                                               logMmboxman("written on FIFOTO\n", 0);
close(fifoto);

/* waiting for response on FIFOFROM */
if((fifofrom = open(FIFOFROMMMBOXD, O_RDONLY)) == -1)   logMmboxman("error in opening FIFOFROM\n", 1);
else                                                    logMmboxman("opened FIFOFROM\n", 0);

if((read(fifofrom, response, sizeof(Response))) != sizeof(Response))   logMmboxman("error in reading FIFOFROM\n", 1);
else                                                                   logMmboxman("read from FIFOFROM\n", 0);
close(fifofrom);

/* if size>0 then the server has to send a buffer of data to me! */
if(response->size)
{
    if((fifofrom = open(FIFOFROMMMBOXD, O_RDONLY)) == -1)   logMmboxman("error in opening FIFOFROM again for the buffer\n", 1);
    else                                                    logMmboxman("opened FIFOFROM again for the buffer\n", 0);

    *buffer = (void*)malloc(response->size);

    if(read(fifofrom, *buffer, response->size) != response->size)   logMmboxman("error in reading FIFOFROM again for the buffer\n", 1);
    else                                                            logMmboxman("read from FIFOFROM again for the buffer\n", 0);
    close(fifofrom);    
}

/* read the response: I release the lock */
if(flock(lock, LOCK_UN) == -1)            logMmboxman("error in releasing LOCK\n", 1);              
else                                      logMmboxman("released LOCK\n", 0);  

return;
}
```

Comment: Please post code. Impossible to fix based on your description.

Comment: Ok I'm posting some of the code :)

Comment: I suspect you would be much better off using UNIX-domain sockets rather than FIFOs for this application.  For a start, they're bidirectional.

Answer (score 0):

So (1) your reasoning about the synchronization of the FIFOs is correct; (2) there is a near zero chance linux is screwing up; so (3) you have a bug.

It's hard to tell but since you are initially opening the server fifo as O_RDWR perhaps you aren't closing what you think?  Perhaps you have a second client running that already has that fifo open as a reader and when you reopen as O_WRONLY it doesn't block?

In any case, your real problem is the protocol you have designed.  You have no need that I can see to need for locks or to keep open and closing the fifos.  You do need a sensible communication protocol.

Typically this is something like:

(1) the server has a well-know fifo that clients open and write to.

(2) clients pass a transaction code or something indicating this is the initial request.  Included is some method of the server establishing a connection back to the client.  This could be an entire path name or just a pid that both client and server use with a pre-ordained path to create the second fifo (e.g. both open "/tmp/myfifo_pid" or some such).

(3) After the client & server open the second fifo, all further client requests to the server include the pid (or whatever) so the server knows where to output the request.

(4) After all is done, the client sends a transaction indicating such so that the server can close the 2nd fifo.  The client does the same.

(5) Repeat for however many clients.

Note that you need to specify a format for your messages.  Time honored techniques are to use a length code (seems to be what you are trying) or some kind of end-of-msg delimiter (e.g. newline).

**Edit**

Possible Message format:

length|trancode||data|

where length tells you how many subsequent bytes comprise the whole message, transcode specifies and operation (e.g. open my output fifo, close it, send data, whatever), and data is whatever is appropriate for the transaction.

Comment: Duck I do close the FIFO. I use the O_RDWR flag so I can keep looping the blocking read: if I use just the O_RDWR if no process is writing on the other side, the read does not block and is active waiting. Impossible: 1) I'm testing it with just on client 2) to access the FIFO chain you have to gain the apposite lock. Also, the FIFO are named ones, off course well known. What do you mean with formatting messages?

Comment: @hysoka44 - You are over-complicating this.  It is best to just get the simplest base case (server/1 client) working first and iterate improvements from there.  Forget about blocking for now and the locks forever.  Concentrate on the design, checking return/error codes, and what happens when you can't read/write one of your messages in one gulp (e.g. see return code of read/write).  The rest will take care of itself once you have the base case working.

Comment: I'm testing in the simplest case, just 1 client. However I'll check the error code to understand what's going on, thanks guys